# Case-sensitive search and replace in elisp in spacemacs

Tags: search, replace, case-folding

Running Spacemacs v.0.200.13 on emacs 25.2.2 on Kubuntu 18.04.

Consider the following code:

```
  (defun xx-ll ()
    (interactive)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (xx-replace-regexp-and-return
        "^[[:blank:]]\*LLA[[:space:]]\*\\(<[ou]l class=\"nicelist\"\\)"
        "\\1 type=\"A\"")
      (xx-replace-regexp-and-return
        "^[[:blank:]]\*LLI[[:space:]]\*\\(<[ou]l class=\"nicelist\"\\)"
        "\\1 type=\"I\"")
      (xx-replace-regexp-and-return
        "^[[:blank:]]\*LLa[[:space:]]\*\\(<[ou]l class=\"nicelist\"\\)"
        "\\1 type=\"a\"")
      (xx-replace-regexp-and-return
        "^[[:blank:]]\*LLi[[:space:]]\*\\(<[ou]l class=\"nicelist\"\\)"
        "\\1 type=\"i\"")))

  (defun xx-replace-regexp-and-return (from to)
    (save-excursion
      (while (re-search-forward from nil t)
        (replace-match to 1))))
```

The `1` in `replace-to` is to preserve case of replacement string. All goes well except that `LLa` and `LLi` leads to replacement by `type="A"` and `type="I"` respectively.

How do I set this right? Also, if I need to make any changes to any initialization variables, I will like to make them ONLY for this function.

Comment: What is the value of `case-fold-search` when you invoke `re-search-forward`? Do you see the same behavior when you remove the first two calls to `xx-replace-regexp-and-return` (those for `LLA` and `LLI`)? If so, try binding `case-fold-search` to `t` in the defun of `xx-replace-regexp-and-return`.

Comment: @Drew Thanks. In emacs, `case-fold-search` is set to t. When I remove the first two calls, `LLA` and `LLa` both convert to `type="a"` and `LLI` and `LLi` both convert to `type="i"` So, it is different from previously.

Comment: @Drew Thanks for pointing me to the missing piece of the puzzle. Read up the documentation. Should have done it earlier. Here is the solution that works. Added `(setq case-fold-search nil)` to `xx-replace-regexp-and-return` and all is well.

Comment: 1. You can **bind**, instead of assigning, `case-fold-search` in your function. 2. Please consider posting an answer, with the solution you found. You can accept your own answer. (Comments can be deleted at any time. Answers in comments don't help much, and they don't count.)

Comment: @Drew I am not sure what did you mean by bind instead of assigning. I am posting an answer below. Please let me know if there is anything I need to change in that.

Comment: You did *bind* it (good). It's a global variable, so if you had just used `(setq case-fold-search nil)` that would have *assigned* it a new (global) value, which would have remained in effect when your function finished. Instead, you bound the value locally, within the scope of the function.

Answer (score 1):

The following change to xx-replace-regexp-and-return solves the problem:

```
  (defun xx-replace-regexp-and-return (from to)
    (let ((case-fold-search nil)))
    (save-excursion
      (while (re-search-forward from nil t)
        (replace-match to 1))))
```

The only change needed was to add `(let ((case-fold-search nil)))`. This comes from [the documentation of the variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Searching-and-Case.html).